# Windows Azure SDK 2.0 for QuickBooks API versUS IPP V3

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm doing custom QB development for a accounting firm and the question I have is has  Intuit announced its decision regarding its chosen, supported API or SDK for QB Desktop and QB online?

Perhaps i've missed something, but it appears from reviewing the code samples in the Windows Azure SDK FOR Quickbooks and comparing them to the IPP API, that there are differences between what one can do with each approach, but neither one seems capable of doing everything the other does.  is the presumption that the SDK is targeting the QB desktop platform and the IPP V3 targetS THE QB Online platform incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Intuit has 3 separate sets of APIs right now, 2 of which are generally available:

1. the QuickBooks SDK (available for general use)
2. IPP, v2 data services (available for general use) IPP
3. v3 data services (available for private BETA ONLY - you need to get approval from Intuit)

The **QuickBooks SDK** can be used to access *both QuickBooks Online, and QuickBooks desktop*. The QuickBooks Online APIs are somewhat weak, and will likely be deprecated in the future.

**IPP v2 data services** can be used to access *both QuickBooks Online, and QuickBooks desktop*. The IPP APIs are available *only to SaaS services* (e.g. you are charging your customers a recurring fee to connect their QuickBooks to your app).

**IPP v3 data services** can be used to access *both QuickBooks Online, and QuickBooks desktop*, but are *currently in BETA and you need permission from Intuit to use them*. The IPP APIs are also available *only to SaaS services* (e.g. you are charging your customers a recurring fee to connect their QuickBooks to your app).

The Windows Azure samples (and the other DevKits) are used to access IPP v2 or v3 data services (e.g. they are not a separate API, they are a code library wrapped around the IPP APIs).

As far as this goes:

> is the presumption that the SDK is targeting the QB desktop platform
>   and the IPP V3 targetS THE QB Online platform incorrect?

Both the SDK and IPP target both QuickBooks Online and QuickBooks desktop.